# In Python, is zlib implemented in C like cPickle?

Tags: python, optimization, zlib, pickle

As you might know, "cPickle can be up to 1000 times faster than pickle because the former is implemented in C". Is zlib also implemented in C ? In fact I'm trying to reduce the time spent by my program while compressing strings with zlib, and still wondering if I should port it to C++ to increase its performance.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `zlib` module is also implemented in C. The actual compression and decompression is implemented by calls to the [external `zlib` library](http://zlib.net/). See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) for details.

Answer (score 5):

zlib is implemented in C.

To improve performance on compression/decompression, you could look into adjusting the size of the buffer, although the documentation argues that the performance gain should be minimal per call of decompress. http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress